# Php to csv export with comma delimiter in separate cells

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv, export

I have found this code here, and I should use it for my website. But although everything seems fine, somehow delimiter is not working. As you can see, I put comma (,) to be a delimiter and when in mysql there is (|) I put it to be changed to comma again to be separate in cells.

But, I got a result that everything is in first cells. There are commas, but it is not split. So, if I click in excel data > delimiter and split by commas - then it is ok.

How to fix this? I am new, so is there an easy specific change here?

```
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Can not connect." . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Can not connect.");
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table."");
$columnName = array();
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $columnName[] = $row['Field'];
        $i++;
    }
}
$columnName[] .= "\n";
$needle = "|";
$values = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table." where id=".$id."");
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) 
{
    for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) 
    {
        $colName = $columnName[$j];
        $count = strlen($rowr[$j]) - strlen(str_replace(str_split($needle), "", $rowr[$j]));
        if ($count > 1)
        {
            for($p=0;$p<$count;$p++)
            {
                $colName .= ",";
            }
            $columnName[$j] = $colName;
            $csv_output_column_names .= $columnName[$j].", ";
            $csv_output_column_values .= str_replace("|",",",$rowr[$j]).", ";
        }
        else 
        {
            $csv_output_column_names .= $columnName[$j]. ", ";
            $csv_output_column_values .= $rowr[$j] .", ";
        }
    }
    $csv_output_column_values .= "\n";
}
$csv_output = $csv_output_column_names."\n".$csv_output_column_values;
$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d");
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $csv_output;
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Don't build CSV files manually. PHP has built-in functions to do it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: Yes, I've tried that solution but no success with my code above, or simply I don't know how to adjust it.

Comment: @user3392725 your code is working fine for me..